# Write $\gamma(t) = (t,t^2,t^3)$ as a graph and a level set

Tags: differential-geometry

My exercise is to write the twisted cubic as a graph and a level set. However, I am not sure what they mean by a graph and level set. Can anyone explain this please? Do they mean, for a graph, $(t,\gamma(t))$?

Answer (score 0):

The twisted cubic $\gamma(t)=(t, t^2, t^3)$ is the curve of intersection of the
surfaces $y=x^2$ and $z=x^3$.

The twisted cubic is the level set of the funtion $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x, y, z)=(x^2-y,x^3-z)$, is $f^{-1}(0, 0)$.

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure how to use your answer to help me understand what they meant by a graph and level set. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @diffGeoLost A level set of a function $f$ is a set points where $f=c$ for some constant $c$